# Is it possible to create disposable password for a user account

Tags: password, users

Some time I want to give access to my computer for my Guests. How can I create a disposable password to my user account so that they have no access to my account in the future, without my permission. The password should be deleted immediately or at logout/shutdown.

Answer (score 3):

There is [one-time passwords](http://scrapcoder.github.com/2012/02/04/using-one-time-passwords-with-ssh-on-ubuntu.html) authentication. However, [Guest Session](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/shell-guest-session.html) can be more secure solution and it available out of the box.

Comment: Sound nice. Have a look.